# New line with ncurses in c++

Tags: c++, return, ncurses, tui

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    initscr();
    while(1){
        int c = getch();
        if(c == 'q'){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, sorry for bad formatting but that is the code.
It's work fine, the terminal catch any character I press but when I press ENTER i can't get a newline.
Why?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know you aren't getting newline? Debugger? Print statement you've omitted from the example?

Comment: I've run this from terminal and when i press ENTER the cursor go back to (0,0) on the same line. just try to compile.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position where I can run the code at the moment--windows box with no curses library installed. If you print out `c` do you ever get 10?

Comment: Yes! If I press ENTER button print 10

Comment: Groovy. You're getting the newline. Why it seems like you're getting a carriage return on the console is unfortunately above my pay grade.

Comment: yes, i'm asking why I don't get \r\n -.-'

Comment: Did you try showing the actual character code `getch` returns? Is it 13 or 10? If it's 13, did you read `getch`'s manual page that explains what happens "If  the character is a carriage-return"?

Comment: Where's the call to `endwin();` before main returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curses has a function for this:

> [nl/nonl](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nl_nonl)
>
> The **`nl`** and **`nonl`** routines control whether the underlying display  device
> translates the return key into newline on input.

The [source-code comment](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/a74363aff427d8cb947df58dcfc9c275a9719cb3/ncurses/base/lib_getch.c#L648) mentions **`ICRNL`**:

```
/*
 * Simulate ICRNL mode
 */
if ((ch == '\r') && sp->_nl)
    ch = '\n';
```

which is a [POSIX termios](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09) feature:

> *`CR`*
>
> Special character on input, which is recognized if the **`ICANON`** flag is set; it is the *<carriage-return>* character. When **`ICANON`** and **`ICRNL`** are set and **`IGNCR`** is not set, this character shall be translated into an *`NL`*, and shall have the same effect as an *`NL`* character. It cannot be changed.